# Help with implicit derivation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Two straight paths from a point P make an angle of 60 deg.

Astrid is jogging on one of the paths, while Beth is jogging on the other.

At a point in time:
Astrid is at 50m with a speed 3.1m/s.
Beth is at 80m with a speed 3.0m/s

How fast is the distance between Astrid and Beth changing at that point in time.

**What I tried: **
[image]

But I get 52.3m/s which is unrealistic, but I don't see where my logic fails.

Found the answer, nvm:
[image]

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own post.

Comment: At the bottom of your post (immediately above this comment), you should be able to see some links saying 'share edit delete flag'. If you truly want to delete your post, then click the delete link there

Comment: @lioness99a it says edit, share and flag but no delete. I'm using the app though, maybe that's why

Answer (score 1):

Nvm, found the answer. Please close/delete this post.

[image]